# Recursive in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, recursion, salesforce

Please help me write a method for finding child objects. The method receives the name of the object and an array of all possible objects. I need to find an object by the input name in this spike, then see what child objects it has, then go through each object in the same way. Thus, you need to find all the children throughout the cascade. The resulting file is this.ArchiveObject[]. The method I wrote "findChildObjects" goes to infinity and doesn't work correctly.

```
public async execute(): Promise<void> {
const templateExecutionSteps = await this.getTemplateExecutionSteps();
// Get global describe
const globalDescribe = await SfDescribe.objects(this.auth);
await this.backup.sobjectKeyPrefix(globalDescribe);

// Get names of user-selected objects
const objectsName = [...templateExecutionSteps.keys()].map(objectName => {
  const describeObject = globalDescribe.sobjects.find(describeObj => describeObj.name === objectName);
  if (!describeObject) throw new Error(`Object ${objectName} not found`);
  if (!describeObject.queryable) throw new Error(`Object ${objectName} not queryable`);
  return describeObject;
});
// Get names of all objects from org
const globalDescribeNames: string[] = [];
globalDescribe.sobjects.forEach(obj => globalDescribeNames.push(obj.name));
// Get global describe for all objects from org
const describeAllObjects = await SfCompositeUtils.describeObjects(this.auth, globalDescribeNames, true);
// Push global describe for all objects result in map
const globalDescribeMap: Map<string, SFDescribeObjects> = new Map();
describeAllObjects.forEach(objectDescribe => globalDescribeMap.set(objectDescribe.name, objectDescribe));
this.objectsArray = [];
objectsName.forEach(object => {
  const allObjects = this.findChildObjects(object.name, globalDescribeMap);
});
```

}

```
public findChildObjects(selectedObject: string, globalDescribeMap: Map<string, SFDescribeObjects>): any {
const currentObject: ArchiveObject = {};
console.log(globalDescribeMap);
globalDescribeMap.get(selectedObject).childRelationships.forEach(object => {
  if (
    this.objectsArray.find(item => item.objectName === object.childSObject && item.referenceField === object.field)
  ) {
    return;
  }
  currentObject.referenceTo = selectedObject;
  currentObject.objectName = object.childSObject;
  currentObject.referenceField = object.field;
  if (object.cascadeDelete || object.restrictedDelete) {
    currentObject.isDelete = true;
    this.objectsArray.push(currentObject);
    const result = this.findChildObjects(object.childSObject, globalDescribeMap);
    this.objectsArray.push(...result);
  } else {
    currentObject.isDelete = false;
    this.objectsArray.push(currentObject);
  }
});
return this.objectsArray;
```

}

```
export interface ArchiveObject {objectName?: string; referenceField?: string; referenceTo?: string; isDelete?: boolean;}
```

Here is the globalDescribeMap structure:

```
'DashboardFeed' => {
actionOverrides: [],
activateable: false,
associateEntityType: 'Feed',
associateParentEntity: 'Dashboard',
childRelationships: [
  [Object], [Object],
  [Object], [Object],
  [Object], [Object],
  [Object], [Object],
  [Object]
],
compactLayoutable: false,
createable: false,
custom: false,
customSetting: false,
deepCloneable: false,
defaultImplementation: null,
deletable: true,
deprecatedAndHidden: false,
extendedBy: null,
extendsInterfaces: null,
feedEnabled: false,
fields: [
  [Object], [Object],
  [Object], [Object],
  [Object], [Object],
  [Object], [Object],
  [Object], [Object],
  [Object], [Object],
  [Object], [Object],
  [Object], [Object],
  [Object]
],
hasSubtypes: false,
implementedBy: null,
implementsInterfaces: null,
isInterface: false,
isSubtype: false,
keyPrefix: null,
label: 'Dashboard Feed',
labelPlural: 'Dashboard Feed',
layoutable: false,
listviewable: null,
lookupLayoutable: null,
mergeable: false,
mruEnabled: false,
name: 'DashboardFeed',
namedLayoutInfos: [],
networkScopeFieldName: null,
queryable: true,
recordTypeInfos: [],
replicateable: true,
retrieveable: true,
searchLayoutable: false,
searchable: false,
sobjectDescribeOption: 'FULL',
supportedScopes: [ [Object] ],
triggerable: false,
undeletable: false,
updateable: false,
urls: {
  rowTemplate: '/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/DashboardFeed/{ID}',
  describe: '/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/DashboardFeed/describe',
  sobject: '/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/DashboardFeed'
}
```

},

[Visual structure of one object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1wRT.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem could be that there are circular dependencies.

Your data model can appear to be a tree, while it is actually more like a graph. If you apply recursive search algorithms to traverse through a graph, you can get stuck in an endless loop. Due to the circular references, it would be like searching in a tree of endless depth.

The solution, is to never process an element twice. To accomplish this, you need to keep track of a collection of processed elements, and check whether they were already processed before.

---

Your `findChildObjects` function could use a `Set` to mark/verify that objects have been processed.

```
public findChildObjects(selectedObject,..., alreadyProcessed: Set) {
  // make sure objects are processed only once
  if (alreadyProcessed.has(selectedObject)) return [];
  alreadyProcessed.add(selectedObject);

  ...
}
```

Of course, you would need to create the set in advance before calling it the first time.

```
const alreadyProcessed = new Set();
...
this.findChildObjects(..., ..., alreadyProcessed);
```

Basically, whenever you call the `this.findChildObjects(...)` you pass along the collection, which makes it possible to detect and skip objects that already have been processed.

Comment: Well, a tree with circular dependencies isn't a tree, but rather a graph, no? But indeed, that's a problem we can find in Dom objects, for example.

Comment: @PhiLho I rephrased that a little. :-)